# Is there any tool for static analysis of Windows Workflow Foundation XAML files?

Tags: .net, static-analysis

The title says it all.

First, is there any dedicated tool that is capable of analysis of Workflow Foundation files?

If not, is there a process that can analyse them, eg. [compile the WF into IL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734733(v=vs.90).aspx), then analyse the resulted IL assembly.

Comment: What do you mean by static analysis ?
Maybe try to save xaml file (FileStream) as xml ? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613434.aspx)

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Static_Code_Analysis

Comment: lol thank you for the link !  here is a similar question / answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893450/reverse-engineer-a-controltemplate/6893720